# Why won't std::string.find() work for "<"?

Tags: c++, string, macos

I have :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    std::string foo = "<!";

    if (foo.find("<")) {
        std::cout<<"Found";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why won't this code find the `"<"` ?
If I change the line to `foo.find("!")`, then it is found. So what is the problem with `"<"` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If successful [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns the index where its argument is found, not a boolean.

Because `"<"` is found at index 0 it returns 0, and in a boolean context 0 is false, so the condition fails. Because `"!"` is at index 1 it returns 1, and in a boolean context that is true.

Instead of testing whether `find` returns true you need to use:

```
if (foo.find("<") != std::string::npos) {
```

`npos` is the special value reserved to mean "not a position" and `find` returns it to say the value was not found.

N.B. when you want to  search for a single character it is better to do exactly that, not search for a string of length one, i.e. use `foo.find('<')` instead of `foo.find("<")`

You could have debugged this for yourself by trying to search for `'<'` in the string `"!<"` and you would have found that the result is nothing to do with the specific character you search for, but only where in the string it gets found.

Comment: It just didn't occur to me. I'm new to C++.

Answer (score 4):

Your `if` statement is not checking if you found your substring correctly, try this:

```
if (foo.find("<") != std::string::npos)
```

[working example](http://ideone.com/3fgAf5)

Answer (score 3):

It does find the "<", at position 0, which becomes `false` in this context.

`find` returns the index at which it found the argument, or `std::string::npos` if it can't find the argument. You do not check for that in your `if` statement.